# How to start the SMS intent in NativeScript

Tags: android, sms, nativescript

I have published an APP in Playstore which is developed using NativeScript. Recently my Application got rejected by the google because of Sensitive permission such as SEND_SMS that I used in manifest. I have to send the Message from my APP side to the customer. I have plan to start the SMS intent so that customer can send the SMS by their own when press a button.

Somebody please help me that How to handle kind of scenario in NativeScript.

Or else is there any other way to do this also please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Just starting the SMS intent do not require `SEND_SMS` permission. That permission is actually used when you want to send SMS programatically form your app. You should be good if you remove the permission.